# Windows 11 + M310 Nightblade doesn't shut down nor restart and audio jack not working

Tags: windows, audio, shutdown

When I shut down or restart my computer using CMD or GUI, the screen does dark as expected but the computer keeps running with lights turned on. I could not start the computer using keyboard or mouse, nor does the power button work.

The only way to start the computer is long press the computer for a forced shut down.

A side problem is that although I'm able to use Bluetooth speakers, I'm unable to connect to the audio jack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solutions and possible causes for unable to shut down

**Cause 1**: Fast startup is not compatible with hardware

Solution: go to `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\System Settings` in Control Panel and disable `fast startup`

**Cause 2**: The computer went into hibernation instead of shutdown

Solution: Run Command Prompt as Administrator and execute `powercfg /H off`

**Cause 3** The keyboard/USB devices are no longer powered when in hibernation/sleep mode

Solution: Go to Device Manager and disable `Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power` and enable `Allow this device to wake the computer` in USB, Keyboards, and Mice and other poiting devices section.

### Solutions and possible causes audio jack not working

**Cause 4** The Realtek audio driver is missing thus unable to

Solution: Because drivers installation requires restart, we need to first fix the shutdown and restart issue. Then download and install [Realtek driver](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/pc-audio-codecs-high-definition-audio-codecs-software), the installation file is called `Setup.exe`